# I can use conditional in prestashop email templates

Tags: email, templates, conditional-statements, prestashop

I have a problem with te tmeplates in prestashop 1.7.2. in International/Translation email body i can use {if payment="bankwire"}Any to say{/if} or i cannot use conditionals in template emails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use conditions in a mail template. You should duplicate template and edit PHP code to use one or another.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify directly the PHP section in PS 1.7 where the email sending it's triggered, and add your own parsed HTML inside strings before actually calling the sending, in the $data section used by Email:Send().

Through my inspection with the Order Confirmation email notification code, I see that a $data array is sent every time to the HTML email template. As you may know, those values inside {value} in the email template are the actual variables contents, coming from the PHP controller or class side.

So, basically, you can do something like this in the PHP class/controller and add new values to the $data array (I recommend creating an override or a hook):

```
//Just as an example with a ternary.
//Note how I use a {} wrapping the string content. It seems to be a convention or something for PS HTML templates, to escape properly variables from normal text.

$data['{your_conditional_html}'] = $some_value ? "<div>This is great!</div>" : "<div>No, this is not great...</div>";
```

Then in your email template:

```
{your_conditional_html}
```

And that's it. Done. You should have now dynamically and validated content in your HTML template. Do whatever conditional logic you prefer in the PHP section, in order to create your HTML or text content sent to the email template.

Regards.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Way better than duplicating the templates!

Comment: In Prestashop 1.7, I have looked for it and it is located in the class `/prestashop/classes/Mail.php`